# How to override a user profile view,, in our own plugin, in elgg

Tags: php, elgg

I have created a new plugin named 'adv' in my elgg site.

And in this plugin iam listing the users.Which using the  view from  other elgg plugin 'profile

ie the page **profile/views/default/profile/listing.php.**

Now i need to set a link in  the existing view of each user.So i have to edit the profile plugin , mainly  the page **profile/views/default/profile/listing.php**

But how can i do this, without modifying elggs default plugin 'profile'.

I have tried a method that i have copied the folder 'profile' from **profile/views/default/profile**  and put it in **adv/views/default/**.But it donot working.]

Is any solution for adding new link to the user view with editing other plugin, only editing our own plugin example 'adv'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to override the profile/listing view, but only when Elgg is rendering your plugin's pages, not to interfere with other plugins that might want to use the core profile/listing view.

My approach to this problem is the following:

1. Create a new directory that will hold the views that you want to override.
   In your case, I'd create the "adv/views/mod" directory within your_site_root/mod.
2. Add the view you'd like to override into this directory.
   Again, your case, copy the profile/views/default/profile/listing.php to the following location: adv/views/mod/default/profile/listing.php
3. Make your modifications to the newly created view.
   You can now safely modify the adv/views/mod/default/profile/listing.php file to your liking
4. Tell Elgg to use the special view when your plugin is rendering the page. This means you'll have to call the set_view_location(..) method either from your page_handler function, or the php files that are referenced by your page_handler and usually prepare the data for the views (like index.php or read.php, but I don't know your plugin's file hierarchy)
   So in your case you'd call set_view_location('profile/listing', $CONFIG->pluginspath . 'adv/views/mod/'); either from your page_handler or from one of the above files.
   Make sure that $CONFIG is present and available by referencing it (global $CONFIG).

Answer (score 1):

Please check if "Use view filepath cache (recommended)", is disabled in the site administration. Because elgg uses hard view cache. Or delete the view_cache file from the data directory. And also make user your plugin is below the "Profile" in the plugin list.

Comment: Guys Please tell me what should i do of this answer (as i am new new to stackoverflow), should i delete it, as it seems there is no more activity on this question, and it is the only answer (and it is even not accepted).